# yii2 RBAC for basic template role for group of users

Tags: yii2

I just want to know how can I assign roles to a group of users in yii2 using DbManager because I have seen a lot of tutorials but most of them are oriented to advance template and I'm using the basic template.
they mention folders like common, backend, that I don´t find in basic template
Can you give me a tutorial or some guidance that I can follow?

thanks

Comment: You can following this link : www.youtube.com/watch?v=eFOIUeU-Y74

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

That will help you add the DbManager for the RBAC.  First you will want to create different roles and then you will need to add the permissions for the different roles.

Then when you create a user you will need to assign that user a role and they will have those permissions.

Here is a snippet from the docs for creating the roles and permissions.

```
<?php
namespace app\commands;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller
{
    public function actionInit()
    {
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;

        // add "createPost" permission
        $createPost = $auth->createPermission('createPost');
        $createPost->description = 'Create a post';
        $auth->add($createPost);

        // add "updatePost" permission
        $updatePost = $auth->createPermission('updatePost');
        $updatePost->description = 'Update post';
        $auth->add($updatePost);

        // add "author" role and give this role the "createPost" permission
        $author = $auth->createRole('author');
        $auth->add($author);
        $auth->addChild($author, $createPost);

        // add "admin" role and give this role the "updatePost" permission
        // as well as the permissions of the "author" role
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $updatePost);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $author);

        // Assign roles to users. 1 and 2 are IDs returned by IdentityInterface::getId()
        // usually implemented in your User model.
        $auth->assign($author, 2);
        $auth->assign($admin, 1);
    }
}
```

This RbacController.php file would go inside the commands folder in the base of your project.  You can run it via the terminal by calling `php yii rbac/init`.

Then you will actually need to check if a user has certain permissions.  So when an authenticated user is performing an action you can call something like

```
if (\Yii::$app->user->can('createPost')) {
    // create post
}
```

where the string bassed to the can method is the permission that you are wanting to check.